# Не меняется MAX_PATH в windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell

При установке ловлю ошибку:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory:
> 'C:\Users\Вячеслав\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_q
> bz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\include\external\com_github_grpc_grpc\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\grp
> clb\client_load_reporting_filter.h'

Залез в реестр, изменил нужный параметр, залез в редактор политики, и там включил длинные пути (хотя windows home). Но ничего не изменилось.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: при установке самого пайтона, необходимо снять ограничение на MAX_PATH, там есть галочка.

Comment: Помогло, напишите как решение, чтобы я отметил

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При инсталяции самого Python, в одном из шагов установки, необходимо снять ограничение MAX_PATH.